# Sublime match if endif block

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way in sublimetext3 (by any plugins) to jump from start of an if block to corresponding endif? Using fortran code. Any other action besides jumping would work as well, like highlight or show line number or ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a sublime package called BracketHighlighter.

**Installation** (extracted from [the author's github page](https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/installation))

> The recommended way to install BracketHighlighter is via Package Control.  Package Control will install the correct branch on your system and keep it up to date.

1. Ensure Package Control is installed.  Instructions are found [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).
2. In Sublime Text, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (OSX) to bring up the quick panel and start typing “`Package Control: Install Package`”. Select the command and it will show a list of installable plugins.
3. Start typing “`BracketHighlighter`”; when you see it, select it.
4. Restart sublime to be sure everything is loaded properly.

Comment: @Scott updated my answer. just install it and it works right out of the box. more details here [ https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter ]